# Rails-like database schema version upgrades for Android

Tags: android, database, schema

So, I'm working with an Android SQLite database, with `SQLiteOpenHelper`.  It seems to have a concept of database versions and upgrading... but it looks like you're supposed to roll your own code to actually do the upgrades, and keep your `onCreate` method up-to-date with your updates.

Coming from a Rails development background, this seems a little primitive.  For the uninitiated, Rails allows you to just write a class-per-version-upgrade, and Rails takes care of applying whichever versions need to be... this applies for DB creation, too; you only have *one* representation of your database schema, the set of migrations.  Rails also does a DB-independent representation of the schema changes, but that isn't necessary for Android because it only supports SQLite (which is fine).

Has anyone written a decent schema migration helper class for Android that allows me to get closer to DB schema management nirvana (RailsEdition(TM))?  It'll save me rolling my own ugly implementation.

Comment: Hey Womble, very good question. I was immidiatelly unsatisfied with the database api provided by android. Coming from the rails background I want to implement rails similar models. Do you have implemented something yet? Thx in Advance.

Comment: @Denis: I've put in my eventual solution as an answer.  Hope it helps.

Comment: I know this is old but just for reference my plugin Mechanoid can do migrations http://robotoworks.github.com/mechanoid/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that I didn't find anything that supported Android, actually worked, didn't require me to subscribe to an insane database world view, and didn't cost a lot (hobby project, no dice), I came up with the following bodgy hack.  It's not clever, but it at least allows me to think about my schemas in a way that I'm familiar with.  I don't expect it'd work real well for a large codebase/database schema, but if you've got that you can probably afford to pay for something.

```
public class AppDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "main";
    public static final int LATEST_VERSION = 4;

    public static SQLiteDatabase open(Context ctx) {
        AppDatabase db = new AppDatabase(ctx);
        return db.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public AppDatabase(Context ctx) {
        super(ctx, DATABASE_NAME, null, LATEST_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        onUpgrade(db, 0, LATEST_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        for (int i = oldVersion+1; i <= newVersion; i++) {
            switch (i) {
            case 1:
                db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE blah ( " +
                        "id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                        "start CHAR(4)," +
                        "end CHAR(4)" +
                        ")");
                break;
            case 2:
                db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE fortnights ( " +
                        "first_day DATE PRIMARY KEY" +
                        ")");
                break;
            case 3:
                db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE shifts ADD top CHAR(4)");
                db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE shifts ADD bottom CHAR(4)");
                db.execSQL("UPDATE shifts set top=start, bottom=end");
                break;
            case 4:
                db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE shifts ADD callout BOOLEAN DEFAULT 0");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice! Did you ever run into any issues with using the ALTER TABLE command? I think some versions of SQLite don't have it.

Comment: Every version of SQLite present on Android releases I've ever used (all the way back to 1.6) appear to support ALTER TABLE.

Comment: It's just dropping columns that is not supported